# Call @Autowire bean through Mockito

Tags: mockito

I have Class A and Class B. B is autowired in class A. Now I want to test the flow using mockito.

So the problem is when I tried to mock the class A and B in my test case using `@InjectMock` its going to class A but its not invoking class B.

I dont want to mock the class B which is autowired in class A, from A its should make call to class B and get the user details data.

```
@Component
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private B b;

    public Users getUsers() {
        Long id = 10;
        b.getUserDetails(id);
// some Logic 

    }

}

@Component
public class B {

    public UserDetails getUserDetails(Long id) {
        // some logic to get users details .. 
    }
}


@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestA {

    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    @InjectMocks
    private B b;


    @Test
    public void testA() {
        Users actual = a.getUsers();

        assertEquals(actual, expected());
        assertNotNull(actual);

    }

    private Users expected() {
        return new Users(); // expected users object 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [@Spy](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy) on `B` in order to use real `B` class

```
@Spy
private B b;
```

> the spy will wrap an existing instance. It will still behave in the same way as the normal instance – the only difference is that it will also be instrumented to track all the interactions with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change **@InjectMocks** annotation on above B to **@Spy** and you should add **@Spy** on above A also. Because you want to use **B.class**'s and **A.class**'s real methods. Why you need to use **@Spy** ?

If you use **@Mock**, by default for all methods, mock returns null, an empty collection or appropriate primitive / primitive wrapper value (e.g. 0, false, null, ...)

If you use **@Spy** then the real methods are called (unless a method was stubbed).

As a result, your creation in ***TestA.class*** should be like :

> @Spy @InjectMocks private A a;
>
> @Spy private B b;